# Try-Catch statement Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
public void payForMeal(double amount) throws Exception {
    if (balance - amount < 0 && amount - balance <= creditLimit) {
        this.strStatus = "Using Credit";
        double newBalance = balance - amount;
        balance = newBalance;

        throw new ArithmeticException("\n\n-----------------------------\n" + "You must top-up your balance\n" + "Your new balance is: " + balance + "\n" + "You are: " + strStatus + "\n" + "-----------------------------\n");
    }//if

    else if (amount > creditLimit && balance < amount) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("\n\n----------------------\n" + "Cost of meal exceeds the credit limit." + "\n----------------------\n");

    }//elseif
    else {
        double newBalance = balance - amount;
        balance = newBalance;
        transCount++;
    }//else  
}//payForMeal
```

when balance is 2 and payForMeal is set to 8 the following prints before the program crashes:

Displaying Account Details:

Cost of meal exceeds the credit limit.

```
Customer ID:       200
Name:              Joe
Balance:           2.0
Minimum TopUp:     2.0
Account Status:    Valid
Credit Limit:      5.0
Transaction Count: 0
```

How can I add a try-catch to stop the programming from crashing but still print out the errors, thanks

Comment: Your comprehension of your own code would be vastly improved if you cleaned up your indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the method which throws the error with the try catch, like so

```
// ... some code

try {
  payForMeal(amount);
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
  System.out.log("An error occurred trying to pay for the meal: " + e.getMessage());
}

// ... more code
```

How you handle the error is for you to decide.

Comment: As explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938323/589259) that code runs, but it turns a programming issue into a program design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do less in your methods. Programming is about problem decomposition and design.

Have a `checkBalanceSufficient` method that returns a *result* rather than doing this within your code. Check what kind of data it needs to return. Don't put in any print statements, that's for your main method or UI related classes & methods.

Don't reuse `ArithmeticException`. The calculations are fine, it is the *result* that you are not happy with. So you need to define your own higher level exception instead (programming an exception is really easy, just extend `Exception`). Preferably your code will never throw an exception due to problems with the input though; you can handle bad input within separate methods early in your code.

If there is any higher level code (i.e. code that implements a *use case*) within a `catch` clause then you are already doing things wrong.